# In Excel 2010 is the worksheet only an absolute in a formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I would like to make a formula that can be fill copied to the next line progressing from one worksheet to the next.  We have a worksheet for each day of the week that is identical in set up and would like Sheet 1 to be the summary specific data in each sheet.  So for Row 1 it would be =Sheet2!$A$1 for Row 2 it would be =Sheet3!$A$1. Is it possible to use the fill to accomplish the change from Sheet2 to Sheet3?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: It's probably not possible, as Sheets don't need to have sequential names. But in your case, the changes you would have to make would be trivial, just alter the first instance of the cell in each row. Afterwards the fill copy algorithm doesn't mess with the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have any header rows, and your summary data starts on row 1, and sheet2 is the very first sheet with the first day's data, you could do something like this on sheet 1:

```
=INDIRECT("'Sheet"&ROW()+1&"'!$A$1")
```

This builds the sheet name reference based on the current row index + 1.